# Fabric3 connect to server that doesn't have a password

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssh, fabric

I have wandboard that I manage to do ssh with paramiko but not with `Fabric3 1.14.post1`
Here is a working paramiko (2.5.0) code with debug output :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from logging import DEBUG, getLogger, basicConfig
from paramiko import SSHClient, Transport

basicConfig()
getLogger("paramiko").setLevel(DEBUG)

class SSH(SSHClient):
    def __init__(self, host, user, password=None, port=22):
        self._host = host
        self._user = user
        self._password = password
        self._port = port
        super(SSH, self).__init__()

        self._transport = Transport((self._host, self._port))
        self._transport.connect(username=self._user, password=self._password)
        if not self._password:
            self._transport.auth_none(username=self._user)

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        self.close()


# Working with both
with SSH('192.168.1.32', 'pi', '-+') as ssh:
    i, o, e = ssh.exec_command('uname -n')
    print(o.read())

print("#"*80)

# Not wokring with fabric
with SSH('192.168.1.119', 'root') as ssh:
    i, o, e = ssh.exec_command('uname -n')
    print(o.read())
```

output:

```
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:starting thread (client mode): 0x7c4a0f60
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Local version/idstring: SSH-2.0-paramiko_2.5.0
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Remote version/idstring: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.9p1 Raspbian-10
INFO:paramiko.transport:Connected (version 2.0, client OpenSSH_7.9p1)
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:kex algos:['curve25519-sha256', 'curve25519-sha256@libssh.org', 'ecdh-sha2-nistp256', 'ecdh-sha2-nistp384', 'ecdh-sha2-nistp521', 'diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256', 'diffie-hellman-group16-sha512', 'diffie-hellman-group18-sha512', 'diffie-hellman-group14-sha256', 'diffie-hellman-group14-sha1'] server key:['rsa-sha2-512', 'rsa-sha2-256', 'ssh-rsa', 'ecdsa-sha2-nistp256', 'ssh-ed25519'] client encrypt:['chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com', 'aes128-ctr', 'aes192-ctr', 'aes256-ctr', 'aes128-gcm@openssh.com', 'aes256-gcm@openssh.com'] server encrypt:['chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com', 'aes128-ctr', 'aes192-ctr', 'aes256-ctr', 'aes128-gcm@openssh.com', 'aes256-gcm@openssh.com'] client mac:['umac-64-etm@openssh.com', 'umac-128-etm@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com', 'umac-64@openssh.com', 'umac-128@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha2-256', 'hmac-sha2-512', 'hmac-sha1'] server mac:['umac-64-etm@openssh.com', 'umac-128-etm@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com', 'umac-64@openssh.com', 'umac-128@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha2-256', 'hmac-sha2-512', 'hmac-sha1'] client compress:['none', 'zlib@openssh.com'] server compress:['none', 'zlib@openssh.com'] client lang:[''] server lang:[''] kex follows?False
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Kex agreed: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:HostKey agreed: ssh-ed25519
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Cipher agreed: aes128-ctr
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:MAC agreed: hmac-sha2-256
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Compression agreed: none
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:kex engine KexCurve25519 specified hash_algo <built-in function openssl_sha256>
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Switch to new keys ...
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Attempting password auth...
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:userauth is OK
INFO:paramiko.transport:Authentication (password) successful!
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:[chan 0] Max packet in: 32768 bytes
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Received global request "hostkeys-00@openssh.com"
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Rejecting "hostkeys-00@openssh.com" global request from server.
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:[chan 0] Max packet out: 32768 bytes
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Secsh channel 0 opened.
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:[chan 0] Sesch channel 0 request ok
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:[chan 0] EOF received (0)
b'raspberrypi\n'
################################################################################
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Ignoring message for dead channel 0
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:starting thread (client mode): 0x7c4a3cc0
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Local version/idstring: SSH-2.0-paramiko_2.5.0
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Remote version/idstring: SSH-2.0-dropbear_2017.75
INFO:paramiko.transport:Connected (version 2.0, client dropbear_2017.75)
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:kex algos:['curve25519-sha256@libssh.org', 'ecdh-sha2-nistp521', 'ecdh-sha2-nistp384', 'ecdh-sha2-nistp256', 'diffie-hellman-group14-sha1', 'diffie-hellman-group1-sha1', 'kexguess2@matt.ucc.asn.au'] server key:['ssh-rsa'] client encrypt:['aes128-ctr', 'aes256-ctr', 'aes128-cbc', 'aes256-cbc', 'twofish256-cbc', 'twofish-cbc', 'twofish128-cbc', '3des-ctr', '3des-cbc'] server encrypt:['aes128-ctr', 'aes256-ctr', 'aes128-cbc', 'aes256-cbc', 'twofish256-cbc', 'twofish-cbc', 'twofish128-cbc', '3des-ctr', '3des-cbc'] client mac:['hmac-sha1-96', 'hmac-sha1', 'hmac-sha2-256', 'hmac-sha2-512', 'hmac-md5'] server mac:['hmac-sha1-96', 'hmac-sha1', 'hmac-sha2-256', 'hmac-sha2-512', 'hmac-md5'] client compress:['zlib@openssh.com', 'none'] server compress:['zlib@openssh.com', 'none'] client lang:[''] server lang:[''] kex follows?False
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Kex agreed: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:HostKey agreed: ssh-rsa
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Cipher agreed: aes128-ctr
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:MAC agreed: hmac-sha2-256
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Compression agreed: none
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:kex engine KexCurve25519 specified hash_algo <built-in function openssl_sha256>
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Switch to new keys ...
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:userauth is OK
INFO:paramiko.transport:Authentication (none) successful!
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:[chan 0] Max packet in: 32768 bytes
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:[chan 0] Max packet out: 32759 bytes
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Secsh channel 0 opened.
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:[chan 0] Sesch channel 0 request ok
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:[chan 0] EOF received (0)
b'wandboard\n'
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:EOF in transport thread
```

I want to do the same thing with fabric (Fabric3 1.14.post1), but it's not working
Here is the code with the debug output:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from logging import DEBUG, getLogger, basicConfig
from fabric.api import settings, run

basicConfig()
getLogger("paramiko").setLevel(DEBUG)


# Working with both
with settings(host_string='192.168.1.32', user='pi', password='-+', abort_on_prompts=True):
    run('uname -n')

print("#"*80)

# Not wokring with fabric
with settings(host_string='192.168.1.119', user='root', abort_on_prompts=True):
    run('uname -n')
```

Output:

```
[192.168.1.32] run: uname -n
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:starting thread (client mode): 0xe3ec2da0
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Local version/idstring: SSH-2.0-paramiko_2.5.0
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Remote version/idstring: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.9p1 Raspbian-10
INFO:paramiko.transport:Connected (version 2.0, client OpenSSH_7.9p1)
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:kex algos:['curve25519-sha256', 'curve25519-sha256@libssh.org', 'ecdh-sha2-nistp256', 'ecdh-sha2-nistp384', 'ecdh-sha2-nistp521', 'diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256', 'diffie-hellman-group16-sha512', 'diffie-hellman-group18-sha512', 'diffie-hellman-group14-sha256', 'diffie-hellman-group14-sha1'] server key:['rsa-sha2-512', 'rsa-sha2-256', 'ssh-rsa', 'ecdsa-sha2-nistp256', 'ssh-ed25519'] client encrypt:['chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com', 'aes128-ctr', 'aes192-ctr', 'aes256-ctr', 'aes128-gcm@openssh.com', 'aes256-gcm@openssh.com'] server encrypt:['chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com', 'aes128-ctr', 'aes192-ctr', 'aes256-ctr', 'aes128-gcm@openssh.com', 'aes256-gcm@openssh.com'] client mac:['umac-64-etm@openssh.com', 'umac-128-etm@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com', 'umac-64@openssh.com', 'umac-128@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha2-256', 'hmac-sha2-512', 'hmac-sha1'] server mac:['umac-64-etm@openssh.com', 'umac-128-etm@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com', 'umac-64@openssh.com', 'umac-128@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha2-256', 'hmac-sha2-512', 'hmac-sha1'] client compress:['none', 'zlib@openssh.com'] server compress:['none', 'zlib@openssh.com'] client lang:[''] server lang:[''] kex follows?False
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Kex agreed: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:HostKey agreed: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Cipher agreed: aes128-ctr
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:MAC agreed: hmac-sha2-256
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Compression agreed: none
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:kex engine KexCurve25519 specified hash_algo <built-in function openssl_sha256>
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Switch to new keys ...
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Trying SSH agent key b'24a1a600a5a6c92ebfd5d46f86bcd30c'
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:userauth is OK
INFO:paramiko.transport:Authentication (publickey) failed.
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Trying discovered key b'24a1a600a5a6c92ebfd5d46f86bcd30c' in /home/ramih/.ssh/id_rsa
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:userauth is OK
INFO:paramiko.transport:Authentication (publickey) failed.
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:userauth is OK
INFO:paramiko.transport:Authentication (password) successful!
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:[chan 0] Max packet in: 32768 bytes
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Received global request "hostkeys-00@openssh.com"
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Rejecting "hostkeys-00@openssh.com" global request from server.
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:[chan 0] Max packet out: 32768 bytes
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Secsh channel 0 opened.
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:[chan 0] Sesch channel 0 request ok
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:[chan 0] Sesch channel 0 request ok
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:[chan 0] EOF received (0)
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:[chan 0] EOF sent (0)
[192.168.1.32] out: raspberrypi
[192.168.1.32] out: 

################################################################################
[192.168.1.119] run: uname -n
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:starting thread (client mode): 0xe3e94278
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Local version/idstring: SSH-2.0-paramiko_2.5.0
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Remote version/idstring: SSH-2.0-dropbear_2017.75
INFO:paramiko.transport:Connected (version 2.0, client dropbear_2017.75)
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:kex algos:['curve25519-sha256@libssh.org', 'ecdh-sha2-nistp521', 'ecdh-sha2-nistp384', 'ecdh-sha2-nistp256', 'diffie-hellman-group14-sha1', 'diffie-hellman-group1-sha1', 'kexguess2@matt.ucc.asn.au'] server key:['ssh-rsa'] client encrypt:['aes128-ctr', 'aes256-ctr', 'aes128-cbc', 'aes256-cbc', 'twofish256-cbc', 'twofish-cbc', 'twofish128-cbc', '3des-ctr', '3des-cbc'] server encrypt:['aes128-ctr', 'aes256-ctr', 'aes128-cbc', 'aes256-cbc', 'twofish256-cbc', 'twofish-cbc', 'twofish128-cbc', '3des-ctr', '3des-cbc'] client mac:['hmac-sha1-96', 'hmac-sha1', 'hmac-sha2-256', 'hmac-sha2-512', 'hmac-md5'] server mac:['hmac-sha1-96', 'hmac-sha1', 'hmac-sha2-256', 'hmac-sha2-512', 'hmac-md5'] client compress:['zlib@openssh.com', 'none'] server compress:['zlib@openssh.com', 'none'] client lang:[''] server lang:[''] kex follows?False
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Kex agreed: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:HostKey agreed: ssh-rsa
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Cipher agreed: aes128-ctr
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:MAC agreed: hmac-sha2-256
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Compression agreed: none
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:kex engine KexCurve25519 specified hash_algo <built-in function openssl_sha256>
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Switch to new keys ...
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Adding ssh-rsa host key for 192.168.1.119: b'6bac39c13ffdaa2687f3d283a7c4de3e'
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Trying discovered key b'24a1a600a5a6c92ebfd5d46f86bcd30c' in /home/ramih/.ssh/id_rsa
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:userauth is OK
INFO:paramiko.transport:Authentication (publickey) failed.

Fatal error: Needed to prompt for a connection or sudo password (host: 192.168.1.119), but abort-on-prompts was set to True

Aborting.
```

I tried to playaround with a lot of fabric env parameters, but nothing seems to work, e.g. no_agent, forward_agent
The key difference is with the Authentication, how can I do Authentication (none) in fabric?

Comment: Please remember that Fabric3 is not an official nor authorized fork of fabrix 1.x. I advise you to use fabric2 instead!
In addition, while you connect using SSH keys, you don't need a password!

Answer (score 0):

Unlike @peshmerge, I love Fabric3 and wholeheartedly recommend it.  That said, when changing settings and env at run time, the trick is to use wrap your calls using `execute` and for password-less, make sure to use the `key_filename` parameter to point fabric to the private ssh keyfile that you want to use:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from logging import DEBUG, getLogger, basicConfig
from fabric.api import settings, run, execute

basicConfig()
getLogger("paramiko").setLevel(DEBUG)

def find_uname():
    run('uname -a')


# Working with both
with settings(host_string='192.168.1.32', user='pi', password='-+', abort_on_prompts=True):
    execute(find_uname)

print("#"*80)

# Not wokring with fabric
with settings(host_string='192.168.1.119', user='root', abort_on_prompts=True, key_filename='/path/to/my_ssh_key'):
    execute(find_uname)
```

Comment: although I don't think this will work, I will test it... I guess so because I didn't do ssh-copy-id, the board by default have no ssh password.